# How to structure jsob data?

Tags: java, json

In My project I am receving json data:

```
[{"mobileNumbers":[{"number":"+9999999999","type":"TYPE_MOBILE"}]},
{"mobileNumbers":[{"number":"+9999999999","type":"TYPE_MOBILE"}]}]
```

But I want like below:

```
[{"number":"+9999999999","type":"TYPE_MOBILE"},
{"number":"+9999999999","type":"TYPE_MOBILE"}]
```

I have contact class :--

## contact class

```
public class Contact {

  private List<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers;

  public Contact() {
  }


  public List<ContactMobile> getMobileNumbers() {
    return mobileNumbers;
  }

  public void setMobileNumbers(List<ContactMobile> mobileNumbers) {
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
  }

}
```

## I have contactmobile class

```
public class ContactMobile {


  private String type;
  private String number;

  public ContactMobile() {
  }

  public ContactMobile(String type, String number) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
    this.number = number;

  }
//setters and getters....
}
```

Here I set up to get json data:

```
List<ContactMobile> mobiles = new ArrayList<ContactMobile>();
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
//here mobiletype and number is the data I am putting..
ContactMobile contactMobile = new ContactMobile(mobiletype, number);

Contact contact = new Contact();

contact.setMobileNumbers(mobiles);
contacts.add(contact);
```

Where I am doing wrong???Why I am not receiving my desire output?please guys suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, library for serialization/deserialization of JSON in Java (e.g. Jackson) works in this way by default so the output you are seeing is consistent.

For example, if you serialize an object of type Contact using Jackson with the default configurations, you should get:

```
{
  "mobileNumbers": [
    {"type": ..., "number": ... },
    {"type": ..., "number": ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

where:

1. the Contact object you are serializing is mapped to the JSON object represented by the most external curly braces;
2. the "mobileNumbers" List of the Contact object is mapped to a JSON array associated to the key "mobileNumbers";
3. each ContactMobile object in the "mobileNumbers" List of the Contact object is mapped to a JSON object with two keys,  respectively "type" and "number".

So now, to answer your question:

> But I want like below:
>
> [{"number":"+9999999999","type":"TYPE_MOBILE"},
> {"number":"+9999999999","type":"TYPE_MOBILE"}]

what you need to do is just serialize the "mobileNumbers" List of the Contact object instead of the full Contact object. How to do it just depends on the library you are currently using.

I hope that helped!